# c# datagridview remove last entry row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have problem with removing last row.

Here is code

```
 private void ponistiPrethodni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int lastEntry = glProstor.Rows.Count - 1;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lastEntry);
        glProstor.Rows.RemoveAt(lastEntry);

    }
```

I get exeption with

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted.

Comment: solved ,  int lastEntry = glProstor.Rows.Count - 2;

Comment: Please add this as an answer so it is easier to find for others

Answer (score 1):

solved , int lastEntry = glProstor.Rows.Count - 2

Comment: Hm... I am not totally sure, but ALL OTHER references to "last row of datagridview" mention the count -1 ... are you absolutely positive about deleting the correct row when using -2 instead??